# Which color of these Swim Goggles would be easiest to spot in/ on warm coastal ocean water?

Tags: sea, swimming, swim-goggles

Which color of these Swim Goggles would be easiest to spot in/ on warm coastal ocean water?

[Aqua Sphere Kayenne Swim Goggles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GBEAD14)

PS: This is not a shopping question (I'm already planning to buy, just need Color Contrast and visibility question for Coastal Ocean water - from people who understand such waters).

One of the reasons I posted the following question, was that a large part of beginners lesson (still learning) was hampered by "sand particles" that got lodged in my eyes, and the water burning/ aggravating the eyes and my patience.

[Any swim goggles that may be beneficial for a surfer?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10738/any-swim-goggles-that-may-be-beneficial-for-a-surfer)

The side benefit is I could use these for Pool Swimming, Open water swim lessons, duck diving lessons, and various other water sports & related activities, if I ever need to/ want to.

I do understand that these are not a permanent solution for a surfer or wind surfer or major water sports, but I'd rather pick the one that has a better visibility if/ when ever they're lost in ocean (or non ocean) water.

**What color(s) would be easiest to spot in warm coastal waters?**

Comment: Not directly related, but possibly of interest: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30579/29604

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In water, during the day, darker colors are easier to see. The very differing contrast will help to spot the goggles if they are dropped onto the sand.

Also, **ocean colors** tend to be **beige, green-blue, dark green, grey**, and **whites**. You don't want anything that might blend with these type of colors, so avoid said colors.

**Black** and unusual neon colors like **pink, red, orange,** and **yellow** will be easier to see.

- **red** contrasts with **green**
- **yellow** contrasts with **purple**
- **orange** with **blue**

And with the sandy sea floor, unless it is dark rocks,

- the black will contrast with the sand
- the red will help to contrast with any algae or plant life.

If I were you, I'd buy the **black** with the **red highlight**.